# Numerologic(Pitagoric) calculations in Python

Tags: php, python-3.x

everybody!

I'm new on Python and I'm using version 3.
I already program in PHP and I have done a script where I enter a string (a name like 'John') and the script returns the number associated to this name, based on a calculation from ASCii table.

The formula is => (ASCii code - 65)%9+1.

Here's my script in PHP:

```
<?php

$entry=strtoupper("Jack");
$value = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($entry); $i++) {
if ($entry[$i] >= "A" && $entry[$i] <= "Z") {
    $temp = (ord($entry[$i]) - 65)%9 + 1;
    $value += $temp;
}
}
$result = $value%9;
if ($result == 0) $result = 9;
echo $result;
?>
```

The above result should be 7.

Here's my script in Python:

```
entry = input("Type your name: ")
name = entry.upper()
value = 0

for letter in range(len(name)):
    while letter:
        temp = int(ord(name[letter])-65)%9+1
        value += temp
result = value%9
if result == 0:
    result = 9
print(result)
```

Well, it's not working, because it seems that Python doesn't run through letters the same way I did in PHP on the first IF statement I used.
Does anybody know how can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!!!
God bless you all!

Comment: I don't get your logic. Why would the `if` from php translate to a `while letter:` loop in python?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your python code.
The biggest one is the `if` from php somehow becoming a `while`(and an infinite one) in python.

The direct translation to python would be(and it should make the code work):

```
if 'A' <= name[letter] <= 'Z':
```

But, you should never loop through indices in python.
Instead, loop directly over the values you want to work with.

Instead of:

```
for i in range(len(some_list)):
    # do stuff with some_list[i]
```

You should do:

```
for item in some_list:
    # do stuf with item
```

---

**Edit:**

This is how the loop would look written in a more pythonic way:

```
for letter in name:
    if 'A' <= letter <= 'Z':
        value += (ord(letter) - 65) % 9 + 1
```

Also, you can see here that the `int()` call and the `temp` variable are not really needed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply.
It's because the if statement was returning some error and I just replace it for a loop to test and forget to remove it.
Whith the first if statement you gave me, I get the error: "NameError: "name 'jack' is not defined"

In your machine does it work?

And can you show me in my code how I can replace the for loop with the one you suggest?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I get your logic, but I think I don't know yet how to create a list in python...
It seems to me that I get a smaller and direct code in PHP, but probably it's because my lack of knowlegde in Python!

Comment: Dear friend, the problem was the input().
I changed to raw_input() and it works just fine with the if statement you gave me!
Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You marked your question as `python-3`. In python 3, there is no `raw_input()`, and `input()` would have worked fine.

Comment: I edited the answer to show the loop modification I had in mind.